# Qt app with dependencies on mac - dependent sdk has @executable_path in otool list... how do I change it?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to build/run/deploy a qt app on mac. It has, among other dependencies, an sdk that I have placed in a lib folder... and set the path in the pro file. The app builds fine, but I cannot execute it.

Running `otool -L myapp` shows, for this particular sdk:

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks/blah.0.dylib
```

If I could copy the `dylib` in a folder like "`/usr/local/lib/`" i would be able to make it work I think... But  have no admin rights.

Without admin rights, I cannot search the system to see what location it may have... but oddly, even without admin rights i can `ls /Libraries/Frameworks` and it only contains Qt frameworks at the moment. `ls /Frameworks` tells me that `/Frameworks` doesn't exist. neither does `Frameworks` (relative to the app dir)

Placing the `dylib` in the same folder as my app doesn't work (I guess mac is not windows lol). I am looking for [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552717/run-qt-app-with-dependent-libraries-on-mac-with-no-admin-rights), but also will need to deploy this app so I must do the `install_name_tool` to convince the linker that the `dylib` is inside the bundle I am creating.

The problem is, as much as I understand it from the [qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html) page, that I need the original location of the app - the original id.

```
mkdir myapp.app/Contents/Libraries
cp lib/blah.0.dylib myapp.app/Contents/Libraries
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Libraries/blah.0.dylib myapp.app/Contents/Libraries/blah.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change path/to/blah.0.dylib @executable_path/../Libraries/blah.0.dylib myapp.app/Contents/MacOs/myapp
```

So, the question is: for the 4th step, what do I use for `path/to/blah.0.dylib`   ? I imagine it is the path the linker thinks it is now... but how do I ask him ? Also... since the previous id has "Frameworks" in its name, can I replace it with "Libraries" ?

Edit: one step forward:

```
install_name_tool -change myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/blah.0.dylib @executable_path/../Libraries/blah.0.dylib myapp.app/Contents/MacOs/myapp
```

the above has the correct address now... but it doesn't work.

Placing blah.0.lib in the Frameworks folder will allow the linker to find it. But install_name_tool doesn't seem able to change that path.

oddly, install_name_tool was able to change some paths for the linker but not others - and once ran with a typo on a name (for a different lib dependency which initially did not have a defined id), I was unable to change it...

How do I remove such a linker path ? How do I change the path once set ?

Comment: I would first upgrade to Qt 5.3. I found many things worked better after I upgraded including the deployment phase which was quite buggy with Qt 4.8. Just a guess...

Comment: can't, I must use 4.8. But Qt version should be irrelevant in this case. Or even the fact that the libraries (some of them, not all) and the app are made using qt. The sdk is likely pure c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your app is a package, 
your app is a special package called a bundle.
your app bundle is a directory...

```
YourApp.app/
       Contents/
            Resources/
                         <images, plists, core data models, etc.>
                MacOS/
                          yourApp  <-- this is the actual executable
           Frameworks/ <- optional frameworks directory
                          blah.dyld goes here
```

the @executable_path is expanded to what ever the `MacOS/yourApp` is
the dynamic linker is then looking for your dyld in `YourApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/...` but I assume it isn't there, so you need to add a build phase to copy it there.

Comment: So I don't need to perform the steps I listed above to make the linker know the dependent libraries are found in the bundle ? All I have to do is place them in the correct location ? And can I still change the (preset apparently) linker path to make it look in Libraries instead of frameworks ? (seems more logical)

Comment: Also, the build phase you mention ... would that be in the pro file ?

Comment: I haven't really used QT builder in a long time.. does it still output an Xcode Project file?

Comment: yes... i never looked at it... just started on mac. I see the dependencies here but nothing so far on how to script anything...

Comment: really all you should have to do is copy the dyld into your bundle

Comment: doesn't work. And in xcode i am unable to change binary locations, or even executable location, which seems to be placed in a very weird location

Comment: I was able to run my app after having the build tool place the libs in destination directory (In that case, Framework) - nothing I did changed its destination. Used the code here http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5469. This still does not answer my question... I am unable to run with that specific library placed anywhere else than inside Frameworks.

Comment: You may link to a dynamic library in another location... if it is in that location when you build, that is where the linker will reference it in your application. You may also use (at)rpath, rather than (at)executable_path, which is more dynamic and reference multiple places: http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/